UML Generalization::isSubstitutable()
On page 180 of the UML 2.5.1 specification under section 9.9.7.4 "Attributes" for Generalization, the default for the Boolean return value doesn't make any sense to me if a null Boolean can be returned. Here is the description:
isSubstitutable : Boolean [0..1] = true

Indicates whether the specific Classifier can be used wherever the general Classifier can be used. If true, the
execution traces of the specific Classifier shall be a superset of the execution traces of the general Classifier. If
false, there is no such constraint on execution traces. If unset, the modeler has not stated whether there is such
a constraint or not.

Default values are meant to be used if there is no other value given; however, this is already the case if a null Boolean value is returned, indicating that "the modeler has not specified whether there is such a constraint or not." Clients querying this attribute would never see the null Boolean if a default is returned and thus could not determine the intent, or lack of it, on the modeler's part, so why the extra default value?
I would think that the declaration of this attribute should either be without any default value, or with multiplicity 1..1 and some default value ... whether or not true makes more sense here than false is also debatable. If it were up to me, I would leave off the default value entirely and just set the multiplicity to 1..1.
Would be nice if someone could explain this to me?

If given then it's what is given. If not then you have nothing at hand an you don't know wheter it's substitutable. IOW ask the modeller or make a guess. Like multiplicities which are also optional.

@qwerty_so Yes, but then why the default value? I assume the intent was to return true if there is no given value, but this would be written Boolean [1..1] = true and not with lower bound of 0.

Well, [1..1] means exactly one, so you must supply a value. Having said that, I'm now unsure about how a default will be specified. I probably have to dig into OCL.

A Boolean primitive type, as well as all of the other UML primitives Integer, Real, String, and UnlimitedNatural, are described in great detail in the OCL 2 specification available on the OMG website. Also, Ed Willink has written an important paper about @qwerty_so OCL: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/346268547_Reflections_on_OCL_2. Booleans can have at least four value states: invalid, null, true, and false (I believe Ed shows that there can actually be five!). AFAIK the specification Boolean [0..1] means that the return value is either null or else true or false.

To my understanding, it is similar to defining a database table column in SQL: If it is defined NOT NULL with a default value, any inserts would not need to provide a value for that column. Otherwise, the column can be defined DEFAULT NULL which would insert a null into that column if none is provided.

see pp. 677 of UML 2.5.1

@qwerty_so From the OCL 2.4 specification (page numbers refer to PDF pages, not the page number printed on each page):

page 173, section 11.4.4 Boolean: "(...) Boolean is itself an instance of the metatype PrimitiveType (from UML)."
But on page 178 under Operations and Well-formedness Rules, it is fairly obvious that a Boolean value can also be invalid or null.


Hope for Ed to chip in. He occassionally posts an answer here. My OCL is very(!) basic.

About the default value:
I think true is a good default value, given the concept of generalization. Normally, if an instance of X plays a role in some algorithm, then an instance of Y, where X is a generalization of Y, can also play a role in that algorithm. For example, if I have a webshop selling bicycles, where Bicycle is a generalization of MountainBike, TouringBike etc, then the sales process for Bicycle also applies to MountainBike and TouringBike.
In other cases, the modeler may wish to set it to false. For example, if I have class Polygon with method AddVertex(), then the generalization of classes Triangle and Square are not substitutable.
About the multiplicity:
I think [0..1] is a good multiplicity. True means substitutable, false means not substitutable, unset means substitutability not guaranteed. If the multipliticy were [1..1], the modeler would not have the option to indicate the latter. For example, the modeler may not have enough information to decide whether all functionality offered for Bicycle also applies to the newly introduced SuperBike.
About the combination of a default value and multiplicity [0..1]:
This is perfectly allright. The default value is the value you most probably want and the multiplicity [0..1] gives you the option to clear the value.
You may disagree with the above and you may wish to discuss improving the UML specs, but that's not something StackOverflow is for.

I have no issues with the default value, nor do I have any issues with the multiplicity. I do not understand the COMBINATION of the two in this case; nobody else seems to see the inherent contradiction here in combining them together.

I saw it but have no good explanation either. That's why I was hoping for Ed. He's the crack.

Vague generalization seems a bit dubious philosophically so [1..1] might be right. But is it wrong? Probably not so [0..1]. The = true default makes it impossible for the value to be initially null, so [1..1] might be implied. However in a dynamic system that tolerates metamodel mutation, a null could be assigned subsequently, so I would leave the spec as is.

@EdWillink Thank you, Ed. BTW I love your "Boolean" conclusions: "...might be right. But is it wrong? Probably not so..." Fits right in with the issue at hand! :)

@RobertHairgrove, you wrote: "nobody seems to see the contraction in combining them". Sure, I don't see the contradiction. I have added a paragraph to my answer about the combination of default value and multiplicity [0..1].  Does that answer your question?

@www.admiraalit.nl "Does that answer your question?" - No, at least not from an implementation standpoint. As Ed Willink has pointed out, "The = true default makes it impossible for the value to be initially null,..." I may be missing something important here. To my understanding, the modeler can make a decision about this attribute value, or leave it empty. How is a client supposed to know what the intent of the modeler is if the empty (null) value is never propagated due to the default value of "true"? If the default were = null, then it would make sense.

On further thought, I think both you and Ed are right ... it is only the initial value which is set to true, and the modeler can set it to null afterwards. The way I was interpreting the behavior was from the standpoint of a database, where if a column has a default value, that value is always inserted into a table if a value for that column is not given. I will therefore accept your answer.

@EdWillink, Why would you need a metamodel mutation? Though the value is not NULL initially, the modeler may set it to NULL afterwards. Even in relational databases, it possible to have a nullable column with a default value; when you update a record, you can set the value to NULL.

Conventional (UML) metamodel usage is that you define the metamodel and then use it in diverse ways for models that conform to it. However the UML metamodel is also a model and so users (e.g. a metamodel editor) could change it.

@EdWillink, yes, but I referred to your statement "in a dynamic system that tolerates metamodel mutation, a null could be assigned subsequently". There is no need for metamodel mutation, because a null can be assigned anyway. I think mentioning 'metamodel mutation' is confusing, because it is irrelevant in this case. Or do I miss your point?
